# Hello world program in Qiskit 1.0

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, qiskit-runtime

How do I write a "Hello world" program in [Qiskit 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qiskit), which should be run on [IBM cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/login) and require less than 600 seconds for implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I am not pretty sure about"Hello World" program as you stated. However, if you want to run a simple circuit on one of the backends that requires minimum time to be executed, then you can take into account the following code:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService


service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")
provider = IBMProvider()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibm_kyoto')


q = QuantumRegister(1)
c = ClassicalRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
qc.h(q)

qc.measure(q, c)
trans_qc = transpile(qc, backend)
job = backend.run(trans_qc, shots = 1024)
results  = job.result()
counts = results.get_counts()
print(counts)
```

I suppose this program is the simplest form which sets the qubit into superposition state.